# Azure App Service is Up and Running but it shows default microsoft page

Tags: python, azure, machine-learning, web-applications, azure-appservice

I am facing a problem regarding deploying my machine learning model on Microsoft Azure. After linking my github repo to azure, it shows that model has been deployed successfully. However when I click on the created app's url, it just shows that "Your app service is up and running.Time to take the next step and deploy your code". I have used linux as OS while creating the service. I can see that my files are present when I click on advanced tools->site wwwroot. But I can't understand the problem as I am new to the cloud services. I'll be thankful if anyone can help me out.(Though somehow I think that the problem is being created due to hostingstart.html. I can see that file in site wwwroot).My app code is in python 3.8.

Comment: Can [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#container-characteristics) be of help? It tells how azure looks what to start

Comment: Tanks but I already took a look upon documentation while searching for solution. I think the problem was that my template  was named as home.html. Somehow I thought to change it to index.html and boom it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, umalik, the problem is from the default page. The app service cannot find your default index page, so the default app shows up.

Follow [diagnostics when you see the default app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-sg/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#app-doesnt-appear).

Comment: Hey, @umalik ,I just generate the answer for others to refer.